# Join two queries with sum of fields as total

Tags: mysql

I have two queries to sum count all sales of products and other for services in the same database, I am wondering if it is possible to make these 2 queries to just one. Not because they are just queries but also because they sum count. I better show the example here

QUERY 1

```
SELECT SUM(totalone) AS `total` FROM `sold_products` 
WHERE `date`=DATE(NOW()) AND `payment_method`='cash'
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT SUM(totaltwo) AS `total` FROM `sold_services` 
WHERE `date`=DATE(NOW()) AND `payment_method`='cash'
```

Right now I add the two values in my PHP code. It works fine but I just want to know how to do this in just one query. I always query the same payment method and the same date, but just two different tables in the same database.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Use two subqueries https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UNION and then SUM the values like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
    SELECT totalone AS `total` FROM `sold_products` 
        WHERE `date`=DATE(NOW()) AND `payment_method`='cash'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT totaltwo AS `total` FROM `sold_services` 
        WHERE `date`=DATE(NOW()) AND `payment_method`='cash'
)
```

Make sure you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, otherwise you will end up discarding any duplicate values in your `total` column, giving you the wrong sum.

Comment: I forgot that the first query is sum totalone and second is sum totaltwo, how would it be in that case ? your answer seems to be the one. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically you fetch whatever column you want and rename it to `total` since UNION requires both your queries to have the same schema. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the UNION operator. You can take the two queries and get them combined as one.

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS `total` FROM (
SELECT `total` FROM `sold_products` 
WHERE `date`='$today' AND `payment_method`='cash'
UNION
SELECT `total` FROM `sold_services` 
WHERE `date`='$today' AND `payment_method`='cash')
```

Here is an article with more information about MySQL UNION:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx